# web mail not sending from one site but is from another?

Tags: php, html, email

ok my father has two websites that i have made, the first is www.ammserv.co.uk and the second is www.ifixboilers.com.

Ammserv has been finished for a while now and im still doing iFixBoilers.com. Before he bought the domain and a server i was using Ammserv to test the new site. [www.ammserv.co.uk/ifixboilers/index.html](http://www.ammserv.co.uk/ifixboilers/index.html)

iFixboilers is based on a form that people fill out and send to him for further contact, i use JS to dynamically change the form and check for errors on submit, and i use PHP to collect the data and send it to him.

On ammserv the PHP works, it collects the data from the form and sends it fine, but on iFixBoiler it does not!

I have checked my code over and over but i cannot find any fault? In the form i have made sure the action has the right address and all the names and id's are correct?

here is my form from iFixBoilers

```
<form name="fix" method="POST" action="http://localhost/PHP/fixscript.php">
<table width="800" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
<td width="230" valign="top" align="right">First name: </td>
<td width="503" valign="top" align="left">
<input type="text" name="fName" id="fName" size="50" maxlength="20" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="230" valign="top" align="right">Surname: </td>
<td width="503" valign="top" align="left">
<input type="text" name="lName" id="lName" size="50" maxlength="20" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="230" valign="top" align="right">Contact phone number: </td>
<td width="503" valign="top" align="left">
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" size="50" maxlength="20" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="230" valign="top" align="right">Email: </td>
<td width="503" valign="top" align="left">
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="50" maxlength="75" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="230" valign="top" align="right">House name or number: </td>
<td width="503" valign="top" align="left">
<input type="text" name="num" id="num" size="50" maxlength="75" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="230" valign="top" align="right">First line of your address: </td>
<td width="503" valign="top" align="left">
<input type="text" name="address1" id="address1" size="50" maxlength="100" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="230" valign="top" align="right">Second line of your address: </td>
<td width="503" valign="top" align="left">
<input type="text" name="address2" id="address2" size="50" maxlength="100" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="230" valign="top" align="right">Town/City: </td>
<td width="503" valign="top" align="left">
<input type="text" name="city" id="city" size="50" maxlength="50" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="230" valign="top" align="right">County: </td>
<td width="503" valign="top" align="left">
<input type="text" name="county" id="county" size="50" maxlength="50" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="230" valign="top" align="right">Post code: </td>
<td width="503" valign="top" align="left">
<input type="text" name="postCode" id="postCode" size="50" maxlength="10" /></td>
</tr>
<tr id="fuel">
<td width="230" valign="top" align="right">Fuel Type: </td>
<td width="503" valign="top" align="left">
<input type="radio" name="fuelType" id="fuel1" value="Natural Gas" onclick="showOptions(this);" />
<label for="fuel1">Natural Gas</label>
<input type="radio" name="fuelType" id="fuel2" value="LPG" onclick="showOptions(this);" />
<label for="fuel2">LPG</label>
<input type="radio" name="fuelType" id="fuel3" value="Oil" onclick="showOptions(this);" />
<label for="fuel3">Oil</label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr id="bmgas">
<td width="230" valign="top" align="right">Boiler manufacturer: </td>
<td width="503" valign="top" align="left">
<select name="gas" id="gas" >
<option value="0">Natural Gas</option>
<option value="Alpha Boilers">Alpha Boilers</option>
<option value="Ariston">Ariston</option>
<option value="Baxi">Baxi</option>
<option value="Biasi">Biasi</option>
<option value="Broag">Broag</option>
<option value="Ferroli">Ferroli</option>
<option value="Glowworm">Glowworm</option>
<option value="Halstead Heating">Halstead Heating</option>
<option value="Ideal Boilers">Ideal Boilers</option>
<option value="Ikon">Ikon</option>
<option value="Jaguar">Jaguar</option>
<option value="Johnson &amp; Starlay">Johnson &amp; Starlay</option>
<option value="Keston Boilers">Keston Boilers</option>
<option value="Potterton">Potterton</option>
<option value="Range Powermax">Range Powermax</option>
<option value="Raven Heat">Raven Heat</option>
<option value="Vaillant">Vaillant</option>
<option value="Viessmann">Viessmann</option>
<option value="Vokera">Vokera</option>
<option value="Worcester">Worcester</option>
<option value="Unknown">Unknown</option>
<option value="Not Listed">Not Listed</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr id="bmlpg">
<td width="230" valign="top" align="right">Boiler manufacturer: </td>
<td width="503" valign="top" align="left">
<select name="lpg" id="lpg">
<option value="0">LPG</option>
<option value="Alpha Boilers">Alpha Boilers</option>
<option value="Baxi">Baxi</option>
<option value="Keston Boilers">Keston Boilers</option>
<option value="Potterton">Potterton</option>
<option value="Vaillant">Vaillant</option>
<option value="Viessmann">Viessmann</option>
<option value="Worcester">Worcester</option>
<option value="Unknown">Unknown</option>
<option value="Not Listed">Not Listed</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr id="bmoil">
<td width="230" valign="top" align="right">Boiler manufacturer: </td>
<td width="503" valign="top" align="left">
<select name="oil" id="oil">
<option value="0">Oil</option>
<option value="Buderas">Buderas</option>
<option value="Danesmoor">Danesmoor</option>
<option value="Firebird">Firebird</option>
<option value="Grant">Grant</option>
<option value="HRM">HRM</option>
<option value="Nuway Oil">Nuway Oil</option>
<option value="Thermeco">Thermeco</option>
<option value="Trianco">Trianco</option>
<option value="Worcester">Worcester</option>
<option value="Unknown">Unknown</option>
<option value="Not Listed">Not Listed</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr id="sevice">
<td width="230" valign="top" align="right">Last Service: </td>
<td width="503" valign="top" align="left">
<select name="lastServ" id="lastServ">
<option value="0">Last Service</option>
<option value="6 months">Less than 6 months ago</option>
<option value="1 year">One year ago</option>
<option value="2 years">Two years ago</option>
<option value="never">Never been serviced</option>
<option value="unknown">unknown</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr id="message">
<td class="form" width="230" valign="top" align="right">Your message: </td>
<td width="503" valign="top" align="left">
<textarea name="msg" id="msg" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr id="message1">
<td width="230" valign="top" align="right">Brief Description of fault: </td>
<td width="503" valign="top" align="left">
<textarea name="msg1" id="msg1" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="230" valign="top"> </td>
<td width="503" valign="top" align="left">
<input type="button" name="return" id="return" class="button" value="Return"  onclick="location.reload;" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="reset" name="reset" class="button2" value="Reset" onclick="hide(bmgas, bmlpg, bmoil);" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button3" value="Submit" onsubmit="checkForm();" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

and here is the php

```
<?php

// VALUES FROM THE FORM

$first      = $_REQUEST['fName'];
$last       = $_REQUEST['lName'];
$phone      = $_REQUEST['phone'];
$email      = $_REQUEST['email'];
$number     = $_REQUEST['num'];
$address1   = $_REQUEST['address1'];
$address2   = $_REQUEST['address2'];
$city       = $_REQUEST['city'];
$county     = $_REQUEST['county'];
$postCode   = $_REQUEST['postCode'];
$fuelType   = $_REQUEST['fuelType'];
$fuelGas    = $_REQUEST['gas'];
$fuelLpg    = $_REQUEST['lpg'];
$fuelOil    = $_REQUEST['oil'];
$lastServ   = $_REQUEST['lastServ'];
$msg        = $_REQUEST['msg'];
$msg1       = $_REQUEST['msg1'];

$fields = array();
$fields{"fName"} = "First Name";
$fields{"lName"} = "Last Name";
$fields{"phone"} = "Phone Number";
$fields{"email"} = "Email";
$fields{"num"} = "House Number or Name";
$fields{"address1"} = "First Line Of Address";
$fields{"address2"} = "Second Line Of Address";
$fields{"city"} = "Town Or City";
$fields{"county"} = "County";
$fields{"postCode"} = "Post Code";
$fields{"fuelType"} = "Fuel Type";
$fields{"gas"} = "Gas Boiler Type";
$fields{"lpg"} = "LPG Boiler Type";
$fields{"oil"} = "Oil Boiler Type";
$fields{"lastServ"} = "last Serviced";
$fields{"msg"} = "Message";
$fields{"msg1"} = "Description of fault";

// CREATE THE EMAIL

$headers    = "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\n";

$headers    = "From: $first $last <$email>\n";

$recipient  = "blah@gmail.com";

$subject    = "Message from iFixBoilers.com";

$message    = "A message has been sent from: \n\n"; foreach($fields as $a => $b){ $message .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]); }

// SEND THE EMAIL TO YOU

mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers);



// REDIRECT TO THE THANKS PAGE

header("location: thanks.php");
```

?>

the only difference between the form on iFix and ammserv is the action

iFix

```
<form name="fix" method="post" action="http://www.ifixboilers.com/PHP/fixscript.php">
```

Ammserv

```
<form name="fix" method="post" action="http://www.ammserv.co.uk/ifixboilers/PHP/fixscript.php">
```

both websites are hosted by the same company, under the same profile for my dad, both have all the same set up?

sorry for the long windedness of this but i really need some help.

many thanks

Comment: What happens when you try to submit on the second site? Do you get an error message, or does it just act like it's sending the email but there's nothing actually sent?

Comment: In looking at your form, am I correct to assume that you are sending the email to 'blah@gmail.com' and making it appear as though it has been sent from the customers (person who filled out the form) email address? If you are sending the submitted form info to your own email address, then your should use an email address domain that matches the domain of the site. Otherwise your email could be kicked as spam since it's not technically being sent from the address entered on the form (and used in the from header of the email), it's being sent from your server.

Comment: as i explained i can send the form data via email from the ammserv test site, but it will not send from the offical site www.ifixboilers.com . all the code is the same except the action on the form

Comment: ok i have set up an Appropriate email for the website .......@ifixboilers.com but still it will not send the email from www.ifixboilers.com . just tested the new email on www.ammserv.co.uk/ifixboilers/index.html and it sent fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

done it by re doing the php

```
<?php

// VALUES FROM THE FORM

$first      = $_POST['fName'];
$last       = $_POST['lName'];
$phone      = $_POST['phone'];
$email      = $_POST['email'];
$number     = $_POST['num'];
$address1   = $_POST['address1'];
$address2   = $_POST['address2'];
$city       = $_POST['city'];
$county     = $_POST['county'];
$postCode   = $_POST['postCode'];
$fuelType   = $_POST['fuelType'];
$fuelGas    = $_POST['gas'];
$fuelLpg    = $_POST['lpg'];
$fuelOil    = $_POST['oil'];
$lastServ   = $_POST['lastServ'];
$msg        = $_POST['msg'];
$msg1       = $_POST['msg1'];

// CREATE THE EMAIL

$headers    .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

$headers    = "From: $first $last\r\n";

$recipient  = "blah@blah.com\r\n";

$subject    = "Message from iFixBoilers.com\r\n";

$message    = <<<EOD
```

First name              : $first
Last name               : $last
Contact Number          : $phone
Email                   : $email
House Name Or Number    : $num
First Line Of Address   : $address1
Second Line Of Address  : $address2
Town Or City            : $city
County                  : $county
Post Code               : $postCode
Fuel Type               : $fuelType
Gas                     : $fuelGas
LPG                     : $fuelLpg
Oil                     : $fuelOil
Last Serviced           : $lastServ
Message                 : $msg
Message                 : $msg1
EOD;

```
// SEND THE EMAIL TO YOU

$send = mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers);

// REDIRECT TO THE THANKS PAGE

header("location: thanks.php");
```

?>